# Cyrillic alphabet doesnt work with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am using SQL Server database, and I need to store some texts written using Cyrillic alphabet.

I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to enter, view and manipulate data.

But when I insert data like

```
INSERT INTO USP14_Table (Tip_DB, Suma_DB, Opisanie_DB,Kategoria_DB, Data_DB, Mesec_DB) 
VALUES ('саса', 21, 'саса', 'саса', 'саса',2);
```

The result is:

[[image: Picture of problem1]

I search the problem, but I only find the following solution. I had to change the column type from `varchar` to `nvarchar`, but this doesn't work.

Comment: You're still using varchar literals.  An nvarchar string literal is prefixed with 'N',  eg `N'caca'`

Comment: Can I use varchar and cyrillic together

Comment: You can use cyrillic in varchar literals and and store it in varchar columns with an appropriate collation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that your database collation does not support the letters.

Right-click the database that you want and click Properties.

Click the Options page, and select a right collation from the Collation drop-down list.

Answer (score 1):

in this case - collation is the worst decision.
just use N symbol before string
for exmpl: select N'Коментатор выше нуб'

Comment: how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).